# Creating a ramdom baseball batting order in excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to build a baseball spreadsheet for my little league team. I have 10 players and 15 games. I am trying to figure out a way to populate the batting order where everyone gets an equal numbers of games batting 1-10 in the order.

Does anyone know of an easy way to do this?

Comment: just move each player down in the order each game when they reach 1st then the next game they become the 10th and so on.

Comment: And by the way there is no way to make them all bat the same number of times in each position.  There are 10 positions on a 10 person roster with 15 games.  Which means every player will bat twice in 5 positions while only once in the other 5.

Comment: Aren't there only... 9 positions in baseball, or am I thinking of Judo? (SO takes a rare turn into the sports world). Also, it's probably a false assumption to assume each kid will attend every game (unless this is some serious kid baseball). I'm a parent and coached some young hoops teams and such meticulous effort will probably get overlooked. Just try to get each kid a turn to leadoff and hope the other parents aren't paying too much attention.

Comment: @pgSystemTester there are some little league rules that allow 10 players (extra outfielder) and others that allow only 9 on the field but 10 get to bat.  While others that have only the 9 on the field but all players bat.  It is way to help every player play and learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it's impossible to evenly distribute 10 players in 10 batting order positions over 15 games. It's similar to trying to divide 15 by 10 evenly. So you'll have to get creative on how to handle the five remaining games (fundraiser?)

### Random but Fair For Ten Games

In answer to your question of creating a random batting order, you'd probably only want to randomize once, and then offset the order by 1 position each game. This will get you each player in one position in for ten games.

### Random Each Game

If you truly wanted random each game, you'd probably have some undesirable distribution with some kids getting to bet first multiple times while others never get a turn (hazards of truly random).

I built out [a quick spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EXMFhFHroVixqOEDzooBaww0vcpljJUrvVYjlXafebw/edit?usp=sharing) on google sheets here that you can see how such a tool could work. If you download and hit delete in a blank cell it will re-randomize the sheet. It's using the functions index and Rank and Rand.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks you all for the help. What I will do is create a random batting order of the kids and then offset it by one for each of the 15 games and then randomly assign the 15 lists to the 15 games so each game is not different by just one spot.